# Prevent ion-badge from collapsing and hiding information

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I have many ion-badge on the same line. Each badge contains an ion-icon and some text. When there are many ion-badge on the same line, the text doesn't show in order to display all the ion-badge.

The HTML is the following (there can be many more ion-badge) :

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-badge slot="end" color="light">
        <ion-icon src="theSourceHere.svg"></ion-icon>
        Text
    </ion-badge>
    <ion-badge slot="end" color="light">
        <ion-icon src="theSourceHere.svg"></ion-icon>
        Text
    </ion-badge>
</ion-item>
```

I have no CSS or SCSS applied other than the one from the ionic framework and here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdWTv.png). I have been looking at the CSS for a while, but I haven't found anything for the moment.

I am trying to allow the overflow-y so the user would only have to scroll through the badges.

Answer (score 0):

Close the `<ion-item>` tag and check if that works

Hope this is what you are [expecting](https://codepen.io/ssharishkumar/pen/mNXJZG)
use ion-scroll and direction attribute.

Comment: my mistake, it is actually closed

Comment: Since you have given slot="end" all the ion badges are moving to the end thereby shrinking the text try removing the slot

Comment: Ok, I deleted the slot = "end" and while I can see more of the text, a part is still cut off, do you have an idea why?